# Microsoft Teams - Send Message To Bot Via Deep Link

Tags: bots, botframework, microsoft-teams, chatbot, deep-linking

I'd like to start a conversation with a Bot with a prepopulated message via a Deep Link (encoded in a QR Code).

I can [Deep Link to a chat with the Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-link-application?tabs=teamsjs-v2#navigate-to-a-chat-with-the-application):

```html
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/<appId>/conversations
```

And I can [start a chat with an prepopulated message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-link-teams#deep-links-to-navigate-to-chat-messages):

```html
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=<user@domain.com>&message=This%20message%20was%20triggered%20by%20a%20link!
```

But I can't find a way to include a message to a bot?

Comment: Could you please send proactive messages to users, including prepopulated messages when starting a conversation.
Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive?tabs=csharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do this by using the bot's Id instead of an email address, with a "28:" at the beginning, something like this:

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=28:[your bot guid here]&message=This%20message%20was%20triggered%20by%20a%20link!
```

the id to use here would be the one in your manifest in the `botId` attribute.

Note that, as with the deep link you posted above, this doesn't actually *send* the message to the bot, it just pre-loads it into the chat text box - the user still needs to click the `send` button (or hit Enter).